# Understanding Inheritance in a basic example system

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a school project that requires us to build a login system using WindowsForm and the requirements are

1. Derive at least a class from 1 parent class
2. Override at least 1 method of base class
3. Call the constructor of the base class from a derived class
4. Demonstrate method overloading with different method implementations for one method name

I'm quite new to the language, but is it possible if someone could explain to me what the requirement wants and maybe afew hints on how to start >.<''

the login system is for customer
and customer has VIP and non-VIP

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a "do my homework" site.  Please post what you've tried and your question

Comment: Sorry, i just didn't know where to start, it's not a must to provide a solution of it, but i just don't understand what the requirements are looking for >.<''

Comment: Then check with your prof.  If you run into trouble, post your code and a question and we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I know where you're at, you do not even understand what the words mean so you can't even begin. Let me break it down. In the art of coding there is a principle called Object Orientated Programming (oop). It has tenets like: reuse, inheritance, polymorphism and abstraction.

So a parent/base class is just a "thing" that has core variables, subroutines/voids and functions that child/derived classes can either inherit from or override with their own implementation. A great (yet very, very simple) example that demonstrates all of this madness is this article using shapes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx

```
class TestClass
{
    public class Shape
    {
        public const double PI = Math.PI;
        protected double x, y;
        public Shape()
        {
        }
        public Shape(double x, double y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public virtual double Area()
        {
            return x * y;
        }
    }

    public class Circle : Shape
    {
        public Circle(double r) : base(r, 0)
        {
        }

        public override double Area()
        {
            return PI * x * x;
        }
    }

    class Sphere : Shape
    {
        public Sphere(double r) : base(r, 0)
        {
        }

        public override double Area()
        {
            return 4 * PI * x * x;
        }
    }

    class Cylinder : Shape
    {
        public Cylinder(double r, double h) : base(r, h)
        {
        }

        public override double Area()
        {
            return 2 * PI * x * x + 2 * PI * x * y;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        double r = 3.0, h = 5.0;
        Shape c = new Circle(r);
        Shape s = new Sphere(r);
        Shape l = new Cylinder(r, h);
        // Display results:
        Console.WriteLine("Area of Circle   = {0:F2}", c.Area());
        Console.WriteLine("Area of Sphere   = {0:F2}", s.Area());
        Console.WriteLine("Area of Cylinder = {0:F2}", l.Area());
        }
    }
```

> Output:
>   Area of Circle   = 28.27
>   Area of Sphere   = 113.10
>   Area of Cylinder...

See here how the class "Shape" has one function called Area. We can use this as a parent class and inherit from it with different implementations of the Area function for different shapes. Obviously the Shape classes Area function is fit for a rectangle but you can see the Circle class overrides the Area function.. This is OOP, we are reusing code in an abstract way with inheritance and polymorphism.

Now you need to code up a parent login class with an Authenticate function and have a derived class called VIPLogin with its own implementation of the Authenticate function.

You will ask, when a user clicks a button to login how do I get the parent Login classes function to run instead of the child VIPLogin classes  Authenticate function? There are multiple ways but I'm going to show you a quick and dirty way, just to make it easy for you to understand. BTW I'm typing all this on my phone so the next code snippet may not compile:

```
class Login {
    public bool Authenticate(string un, string pw) {
      //ToDo: login using database or openid or etc
         return true;
       }
      }

class VIPLogin : Login {
    public bool Authenticate(bool isVIP, string un, string pw) {
       // if it's not a VIP (like checkbox control ticked) use the generic parent class
       if (!isVIP) {
         return base.Authenticate(un,pw);
       }
       else {
      //ToDo: VIP login using database or openid or etc
         return true;
        }
      }
      }
```

Calling code:

```
VIPLogin obj = new VIPLogin();
if ( obj.Authenticate(chkIsVip.Checked, txtUN.Text, txtPW.Text) ) {
   // login was successful 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :D I'll try to understand it and ask if i'm lost

Comment: Don't forget to mark answers as correct (it's the holo tick box under the score of my answer)